# How do I make two unioned LINQ statements async?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

```
        var primaryApplicationUsers = _context.ApplicationActivities
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(applicationActivity => TimeSince(applicationActivity.ApplicationUseDate).Days <= days)
            .Where(applicationActivity => applicationActivity.PatientApplication == primaryApplicationOfInterest)
            .Select(applicationActivity => applicationActivity.ApplicationUserId)
            .Distinct();

            var secondaryApplicationUserCount = _context.ApplicationActivities
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(applicationActivity => TimeSince(applicationActivity.ApplicationUseDate).Days <= days)
                .Where(applicationActivity => applicationActivity.PatientApplication == secondaryApplicationOfInterest)
                .Where(applicationActivity => primaryApplicationUsers.Any(primaryApplicationUser => primaryApplicationUser == applicationActivity.ApplicationUserId))
                .Select(applicationActivity => applicationActivity.ApplicationUserId)
                .Distinct()
                .Count();
```

The above code is what I currently have. I am grabbing a list of scalar numbers from the first statement, and then in the second statement I am grabbing the same type of information but I want to only grab back the entries that contain the list of scalar numbers from the first statement.

I do not know how to make this statement async.

Comment: I think you should try making these queries execute server side rather than making them async. Client async processing will just slow them down additionally (they are already slowed down due to retrieving the whole table and processing it in memory - twice).

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier and more performant for you to fetch user data from an external source in one shot, and return something more complex than just a scalar.  The more complex objects should provide properties you can reference to later on.

```
var users = _context.ApplicationActivities
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(act => 
        TimeSince(act.ApplicationUseDate).Days <= days
        && act.PatientApplication == primaryApplicationOfInterest // optional, for performance
        && act.PatientApplication == secondaryApplicationOfInterest // optional, for performance
    )
    .GroupBy(act => act.ApplicationUserId)
    .Select(grp => new {
        ApplicationUserId = grp.Key,
        isPrimary = grp.Any(act => act.PatientApplication == primaryApplicationOfInterest),
        isSecondary = grp.Any(act => act.PatientApplication == secondaryApplicationOfInterest)
    })
    .ToList(); // execute it, so it only calls the server once even when 'users' is referenced multiple times
```

Then use those properties in other logic that can now be much simpler because it can make use of the more descriptive user objects.

```
var primaryApplicationUsers = 
    users
    .Where(user => user.isPrimary)
    .Select(user => user.ApplicationUserId);

var secondaryApplicationUserCount = 
    users
    .Where(user => user.isPrimary && user.isSecondary) // you can do the 'any' approach but I believe this is equivalent
    .Count();
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you so much for helping me. I think you need to use || instead of && in your first statement when separating the primary and secondary application, but outside of that, I tested this and its awesome. I'd give you a check mark but the site isn't allowing me to. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Glad it helped.  No worries about the check.  You can't do that until you have 10pts.  But you should still be able to upvote.  Click the up arrow.